# Flutter Android app not complied and gives error as below

Tags: android, flutter, compiler-errors

I have some issue for the project in flutter so I thought of creating a new project and just updating the `pubspec.yaml` file.

I tried to run the project but end up with following errors.

```
The plugin `device_id` is built using an older version of the Android plugin API which assumes that it's running in a full-Flutter environment. It may have undefined behaviors when Flutter is integrated into an existing app as a module.
The plugin can be updated to the v2 Android Plugin APIs by following https://flutter.dev/go/android-plugin-migration.
Launching lib/main.dart on ASUS X00TD in debug mode...
Running Gradle task 'assembleDebug'...
Note: Some input files use or override a deprecated API.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:deprecation for details.
Note: /Library/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/device_info-0.4.1+4/android/src/main/java/io/flutter/plugins/deviceinfo/DeviceInfoPlugin.java uses or overrides a deprecated API.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:deprecation for details.
Note: /Library/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/firebase_messaging-6.0.9/android/src/main/java/io/flutter/plugins/firebasemessaging/FirebaseMessagingPlugin.java uses or overrides a deprecated API.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:deprecation for details.
Note: /Library/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/path_provider-1.5.1/android/src/main/java/io/flutter/plugins/pathprovider/PathProviderPlugin.java uses or overrides a deprecated API.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:deprecation for details.
/Library/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/shared_preferences-0.5.6/android/src/main/java/io/flutter/plugins/sharedpreferences/SharedPreferencesPlugin.java:25: warning: [deprecation] getFlutterEngine() in FlutterPluginBinding has been deprecated
    setupChannel(binding.getFlutterEngine().getDartExecutor(), binding.getApplicationContext());
                        ^
1 warning
Note: /Library/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/video_player-0.10.5/android/src/main/java/io/flutter/plugins/videoplayer/VideoPlayerPlugin.java uses or overrides a deprecated API.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:deprecation for details.
Finished with error: Gradle build failed to produce an .apk file. It's likely that this file was generated under /Users/me/AndroidStudioProjects/sample/build, but the tool couldn't find it.
```

why is this so is a mystery to me :(